# Not specifying Gradle minor version

Tags: gradle

Using gradle:

Is it possible to set the dependencies such that minor versions are auto upgrading? For instance, I would like gradle to automatically pick the latest guava 11 minor version.

Adding

`compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11'`

unless of

`compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2'`

do not seems to work.

Comment: Does it work: `compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.+`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax to use is "11.+" if you want any minor revision above 11.0.0.

If you want for example 11.0.2 but not 11.1.0, you can use "11.0.+".

Using "11+" will probably also find 12.0.0 and above, so would not work as well.

This is mentioned in [the Gradle user's guide](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html), where it's referred to as a *dynamic version*.

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with:

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.+
```